# Spacy: what algorithm is used for word vectors?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, spacy

The question is clear, just would like to know what algo is used: CBOW, Skipgram, SGNS, Glove? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are included as part of a model, so there's no fixed algorithm, though in practice most use GloVe. You can check by looking at the model detail page, like [this one](https://spacy.io/models/en#section-en_core_web_md) for the medium sized English corpus.

Comment: oh sorry, I don't know how I missed that part and didn't see the GloVe mention. thank you so much

Comment: Is this still true for the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_lg` models?  Second link above forwards to https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity which doesn't mention the specific embedding algorithm.